# Swap out old project with new one

Tags: xcode, app-store

I have an existing project, quite old, with its own support system: in-app purchases, links on web pages, etc.

I would like to overhaul the app significantly front and back end, so much so that basically none of the original code will remain. Maybe even write it in Swift instead of Objective-C, mostly because it's getting harder and harder to find Objective-C documentation.

Is it possible to set up the new app in Xcode so that for all intents and purposes, the app store just considers it to be a new version of the existing app? The in-app purchases work with it, the links to the app store still work, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, no problem. As long as the new app has the same bundle ID as the old app (`CFBundleIdentifier` in the *Info.plist*), it is the same app in the eyes of the App Store and Apple. You can change everything else about it and they won't care: icons, user-facing name (CFBundleDisplayName), underlying language, interface, major functionality even. The in-app purchases are attached to that bundle ID so they just keep on working; the links to the app store won't change. You can start a completely new project, from scratch, and as long as the bundle ID is the old bundle ID, it's the same app.

Comment: Just to give an example, my Zotz! app went through a transition like this when I changed from Objective-C to Swift. I took the opportunity to start over from scratch. No problem; it's the same app, to Apple.

Comment: Thanks, didn't expect it to be so easy. Thought there might be hidden folders or UUIDs to modify.

Comment: Actually I need supplement one missing point of this answer. I used same bundle id and bundle name for the new swift project to replace the legacy react-native and obj-c project. However got weired error: "ITMS-90129: The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken" when I am uploading the App to the store or doing the validation. After several hours troubleshooting, turns out the Target name should be the same, otherwise that strange error message would drive you crazy.

Comment: @matt - I know this is an old answer but I was wondering - would things like UserDefaults still persist on the new version of the app ? Lets say I saved some data on UserDefaults or CoreData on the old version of the app and the users now installed the new version - am I able to access the data saved on the old version in the new version assuming I set everything up right and I have used the same bundle id. Thanks in advance.